# Python 2.7 SimlpeQueue Import Error (a bug?)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-2.7

```
$ python2.6 -c 'from multiprocessing.queues import SimpleQueue'
$ python2.7 -c 'from multiprocessing.queues import SimpleQueue'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 22, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock, BoundedSemaphore, Semaphore, Condition
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 33, in <module>
    " function, see issue 3770.")
ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.

$ uname -a
Linux xxx-ubuntu-64 2.6.35-22-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 20:45:36 UTC 2010 x86_64  GNU/Linux
```

Comment: So which platform are you using.

Comment: vmware esxi 4.1 , I would run `uname -a && python2.7 -V` when I get to the University and post it here (already on the road...)

Comment: Since it told you check this: http://bugs.python.org/issue3770

Comment: The bug just explains that it's broken. It doesn't suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently fixed this in Ubuntu for Python3: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/python3.1/+bug/630511

The report for 2.7 is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/683027

Comment: I am having the same problem. Everything went fine in python2.6 but have this error in 2.7.

What is the fix? Anyone get it fixing? It is important that i cannot switch back to python2.6 but anyone get it working on 2.7?

I am using gentoo linux kernel 2.6.34

Comment: has it been fixed? I am also a gentoo user.